# how to disable user interaction in a UICollectionView while an interaction is occurring

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to disable scrolling in a UICollectionView when the contentOffset is smaller or equal to zero.
While the scroll is happening.

Code:

```
extension MyController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollView.contentOffset: \(scrollView.contentOffset)")

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
            scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

this only disables the interaction when the user stops scrolling.

How can i disable the interaction while the scroll is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it that way.

You should look at the UIScrollViewDelegate : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate and maybe try to set the contentOffset of your collectionview back to 0 when the user tries to scroll too far.